# what is S3Bucket and S3Key in function when deploy Lambda Functions with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

This is my lambda cft, I uploaded my jar file to s3 bucket, what is S3Bucket and S3Key in this section? and what does !Sub means in S3Key.

```
ConfigurationLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: 'configuration service test'
      FunctionName: 'configurationTest'
      Handler: lambda.handler.EventHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: Java 11
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 120
      Code:
        S3Bucket: 
        S3Key: !Sub 
      Role: !GetAtt ConfiguratioLambdaRole.Arn
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is S3Bucket and S3Key in this section?

- `S3Bucket` - your bucket name where you placed your jar
- `S3Key` - name of jar file in the bucket

Use of [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) does not make sense in your example. But you would use if if you wanted to parametrize your `S3Key` based on, e.g., input parameters to your template.